# Run Python Script when another program is started

Tags: python, embed, exe

How to do I get a script to run when another EXE is started?

Say I want to log every time I start Google Chrome in one day. I want to have a script run when I first hit that Chrome exe. I created something that monitored the processes currently running on the pc and if Chrome popped up it created a log.

In the end, I hate having a script run at all times in the background. I'd love personally to have it embedded in the Chrome exe so that both are started when the program is executed. I know I could create a python shortcut to use instead of a Chrome shortcut, but that's not really what I am looking for.

Is there some sort of registry tweak that could do this or can you simply open an exe and embed some sort of code that would accomplish this? I'm not looking for a python specific answer, any help is appreciated.

Chrome is just an example, I'd like to use it for a few daily fun monitoring things for myself.

Comment: You could just use a batch file or write your own program that launches chrome and your python script. You wouldn't have the icon but it would work.

Comment: What operating system are you using, Windows? You could always change the `Chrome.exe` to a python script that logs the time to a log file then calls `Chrome.exe` in a subprocess. Something like `call['/path/to/chrome.exe &', shell=True]`, though I'm not sure if that's the syntax for Windows.

Comment: Assuming this is windows, you can monitor processes via WMI Win32_ProcessStartTrace. You'd have to go through the win32 calls and there will be flaming hoops along the way. It would be easier in visual basic or C# but the win32 python stuff will work also.